# Why can't I get the rate-limit to kick-in when using this AspNetCoreRateLimit middleware for Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong... I'm using this middleware to throttle the number of API calls that a client can make against my endpoints:
https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware

I can't get this rate-limiting to kick-in. Here's my Startup.cs (relevant portions):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // needed to load configuration from appsettings.json
    services.AddOptions();

    // needed to store rate limit counters and ip rules
    services.AddMemoryCache();

    //load general configuration from appsettings.json
    services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));

    // inject counter and rules stores
    services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
    services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();

    // https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793
    // the IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default.
    // the clientId/clientIp resolvers use it.
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // configuration (resolvers, counter key builders)
    services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();

    // Configure strongly-typed configuration settings objects
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
    var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            corsBuilder => corsBuilder.WithOrigins("*")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Ensure that the CORS call is before UseMvc
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseIpRateLimiting();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

}
```

And my appsettings.json file:

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
      "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
      "StackBlockedRequests": false,
      "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
      "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
      "HttpStatusCode": 429,
      "GeneralRules": [
        {
          "Endpoint": "*",
          "Period": "10s",
          "Limit": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

FYI, I've tried both EnableEndpointRateLimiting as "true" and "false" and neither one had an effect.

My test API calls are all going through... when I expect to get throttled!

Answer (score 5):

This turned out to be a very silly mistake on my part.  I had the IpRateLimiting session nested within an "AppSettings" section in my appsettings.json file when it should have been specified at the root level.

Comment: You should accept this as the accepted answer seeing how you did answer the question :-)